# How to use ECPG in MSVC

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, postgresql

I'm in the early development of a software and I'm trying to figure out how to use ecpg. I've managed to build **PostgreSQL 9.0.4** using **MSVC 2010** and have successfully built a test program to ensure it works. (http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/accessing-postgresql-cc, except modified for Windows.)

However I don't know how to build, what to "#include" in the source, etc. for ecpg. I've found plenty of syntax examples but nothing in the way of a test program or walk-though. Even something from a previous version (8.4.x) would be of help.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK first you need embedded SQL C file (with `pgc` extension). Simple example:

```
int main(void)
{
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    int ordinaryInt;
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    EXEC SQL CONNECT TO tcp:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres AS myconnection USER postgres USING '12345';

    EXEC SQL INSERT INTO t (value) VALUES ('abcdefgj');
    EXEC SQL COMMIT;

    EXEC SQL DISCONNECT myconnection;

    return 0;
}
```

Connection string is explained well in [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg-connect.html). After that you need `ecpg.exe`, to transform above code into well-known C code:

> Before compiling you run the file through the embedded SQL C
>   preprocessor, which converts the SQL statements you used to special
>   function calls. After compiling, you must link with a special library
>   that contains the needed functions.

For example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\ecpg.exe" -o ecpgTest.c ecpgTest.pgc
```

Your generated C code looks like this:

```
/* Processed by ecpg (4.2.1) */
/* These include files are added by the preprocessor */
#include <ecpglib.h>
#include <ecpgerrno.h>
#include <sqlca.h>
/* End of automatic include section */

#line 1 "ecpgTest.pgc"
int main(void)
{
    /* exec sql begin declare section */


#line 4 "ecpgTest.pgc"
 int ordinaryInt ;
/* exec sql end declare section */
#line 5 "ecpgTest.pgc"


    { ECPGconnect(__LINE__, 0, "tcp:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" , "postgres" , "'12345'" , "myconnection", 0); }
#line 7 "ecpgTest.pgc"


    { ECPGdo(__LINE__, 0, 1, NULL, 0, ECPGst_normal, "insert into t ( value ) values ( 'abcdefgj' )", ECPGt_EOIT, ECPGt_EORT);}
#line 9 "ecpgTest.pgc"

    { ECPGtrans(__LINE__, NULL, "commit");}
#line 10 "ecpgTest.pgc"


    { ECPGdisconnect(__LINE__, "myconnection");}
#line 12 "ecpgTest.pgc"


    return 0;
}
```

Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.0\include` path in Additional Include Directories (Configuration Properties → C/C++) and put `libecpg.lib` into Additional Dependiences (Linker → Input) probably you need to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.0\lib` path into Additional Library Directiories (Linker → General) and you're ready to go (note that some DLLs are located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot later in the week and tell you how it goes.

Comment: I am following exact same step for PostgressSQL 11, but i am getting error `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _ECPGconnect referenced in function _main` while building the project. Anything i may be missing? I have been able to precompile the file with "*.pgc".